# Maintain scroll position when expanding <li> item

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a bootstrap side menu that I am making. There are are `<li>`'s that can be expended and collapsed to display or hide additional menus/links.

Currently when i open the `<li>` the scroll position of the page is reset back to the top. 
I would like the page to maintain its scroll position when the `<li>` is opened.

This is a snippet:

```
 <div id="wrapper">

<!-- Sidebar -->
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

  <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
  <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="/">
    <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
      <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">Business Centre</div>
  </a>

        <!-- Nav Item - Setting Collapse Menu -->
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseAccount" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseAccount">
      <i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
      <span>Account</span>
    </a>
    <div id="collapseAccount" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingAccount" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
      <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
        <a class="collapse-item" href="login.html">Membership</a>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="login.html">Information</a>
        <a class="collapse-item" href="login.html">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
    </ul>
     </div>
```

Can anyone help with the code or point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or codepen! it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its due to the `#` you use in `href` replace it with

> href="JavaScript:Void(0);"

like

```
<a class="nav-link collapsed" href="JavaScript:Void(0);" ...
```

Second solution

> Just use "#/" or "#!" instead of "#" and the page won't jump.